# Exception while using JavaMail with Google AppEngine: How to fix this?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I am trying to write a Java program using JavaMail to send an email between 2 users. I have NOT added mail.jar and activation.jar files to my appengine project as I read somewhere that this would cause exceptions to be thrown since the functionality is already available with the appengine .jar files. But my program is throwing the following exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'mail' or call 'Send()' was not found.
- Hide quoted text -
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:95)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.doSend(MailServiceImpl.java:95)
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.send(MailServiceImpl.java:32)
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.sendMessage(GMTransport.java:247)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:95)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
at weatherForecast.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:40)
```

I read in the following post: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8589 that I need to remove appengine .jar files from my project to make things work. But my web application also involves rendering a .jsp file populated with some data which is the welcoming page of my Google App when deployed on google appengine and the project fails to work once I remove the .jars. It does help me in getting rid of the exception though. Can anyone please suggest a way to write an email program and make it work on a google appengine project?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you are still somehow accidentally including a .jar file that shouldn't be included.

Right click on your project folder and check:

- Properties -> java build path
- Properties -> Java EE Module dependencies

And also make sure you the jar is not in `/war/WEB-INF/lib/`, jars that should not be uploaded to google should be stored in a separate location of your project, i recommend `/lib/`.

Comment: Alright.I will have a check on that. Thanks for your reply :-) 
- Harini

Comment: How do I know which jars shouldn't be included?

Comment: Remove all JAR files except for the ones that are needed to compile your application. ie, delete/remove it from your app inside eclipse, to see if the application can still run in "Development mode" on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flexible, this is because Google does not support [Mail service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/) in the flex environment. Java Mail with the built-in Mail service in GAE are seemed to be designed to work only in the standard Java framework on this [Migration tips.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating). In flexible, three third party's mail API are introduced to be used instead. You may use GMail API for another option.