# How to use javamail and appengine API together?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I found this topic: [Exception while using JavaMail with Google AppEngine: How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285405/exception-while-using-javamail-with-google-appengine-how-to-fix-this)

I have same problem, and I need to use the Javamail API and GAE API together. I create an app run on PC which uses for sending emails. I use javamail API and it works fine. Then I create an app run on GAE to collect customer's feedbacks, then save them in Datastore. So I add to the PC app a function which uses for retrieving data from Datastore. Then I have to use the appengine-api.jar. The code is compiled without problem. But it throws exception in runtime:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'mail' or call 'Send()' was not found.
```

I find out that there is javax.mail.* inside appengine-api.jar and this maybe conflicts with javamail.jar. I test in some case:

Case 1: Keep javamail.jar, remove appengine-api.jar. It sends mails ok.

Case 2: Keep javamail.jar, remove only directory javax inside appengine-api.jar. It still throws the above exception.

Case 3: remove javamail.jar, keep appengine-api.jar. I intends to use javax.mail.* in appengine-api.jar to send mails. It compiles ok, but throws the above exception in runtime.

I use command line to make this app. I don't use -classpath variable, I copy all needed jar files in .../jdk1.7.0_55/jre/lib/ext

How can I use javamail.jar and appengine-api.jar together ?

**Update:** Maybe I didn't say it clear. I don't send mail from appengine. I send from a PC app. In that PC app I have to use appengine-api.jar to retrieve data from Datastore. So I need both .jar api files in my PC app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It solved.**

As I described above, it doesn't work even if I completely delete the directory javax.* in appengine-api.jar. It just works only if I remove that jar file from /jre/lib/ext. I think there are still many "traces" in appengine-api.jar that affect to javamail.jar. After looking in that jar file, I found out there are 3 files in appengine-api.jar/META-INF/ which are affect to javamail.jar:

```
jamamail.address.map
javamail.charset.map
javamail.providers
```

I delete those 3 files and it works! That's enough, I don't have to delete the directory javax.* anymore, just delete those 3 files.

I don't think this is the best solution but till now I can't find another solution for using both javamail.jar and appengine-api.jar in PC app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail ? On AppEngine, sending mail is a managed service (unless you go through sockets).

**Do not include javamail.jar**

This is how to send an email out :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

String msgBody = "...";

try {
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                     new InternetAddress("user@example.com", "Mr. User"));
    msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
    msg.setText(msgBody);
    Transport.send(msg);

} catch (AddressException e) {
    // ...
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    // ...
}
```

On the development server, no mail gets sent but will be logged on the console. 
Also, read carefully the paragraph on the allowed senders, that's usually the next question.

Comment: I know, but I don't send mail from appengine. I send from a PC app. In that PC app I have to use appengine-api.jar to retrieve data from Datastore.